SSIS package error - File/Process is not in path - happens inconsistently
I have an SSIS package that requires access to a file on a file server.
I have a stored procedure that can execute that package (it uses the system stored procs provided in SSISDB).
Here is the issue/question.
When I execute that stored proc from my office computer via Management Studio while logged in under my Windows ID, I get an error that says
Error Message:
[Task Name]:Error: File/Process "\some network file location" is not in path.
Run Integrata API:Error: There were errors during task validation.
However, when I log in to the server machine where SQL Service is running under my Windows ID and run the stored proc in Management Studio, the package completes successfully.
Another test I did was this. I ran xp_cmdshell 'mkdir' on the network folder location where I am getting the error, it runs successfully in both scenarios.
Please ask any questions if I need to clarify the symptoms and please advise on what direction I need to further investigate to understand the root cause.
